# Angular: Use Renderer 2 to Add CSS Variable

Tags: angular, css-variables, angular-renderer

Is it possible to add inline style css variable using `Renderer2`?

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Output, ViewChild, Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
})
export class CollapsibleComponent implements OnChanges {

  @ViewChild('collapsibleContent') collapsibleContent: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.measureCollapsibleContents()
  }

  measureCollapsibleContents() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.collapsibleContent.nativeElement, '--expanded', this.collapsibleContent.nativeElement.firstElementChild.offsetHeight + 'px' )
  }

}
```

'--expanded' isn't a proper css property so angular won't add any style to my div.

If I do add a proper css property it will work like the code below.

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.collapsibleContent.nativeElement, 'top', this.collapsibleContent.nativeElement.firstElementChild.offsetHeight + 'px' )
```

the output for my div will be

```
<div style="top: 160px">...</div>
```

I would like to achieve something like below

```
<div style="--expanded: 160px">...</div>
```

I have also tried `[ngStyle]` but that also doesn't render any value but the style attribute.

```
[ngStyle]="{'--expanded': expandedHeight }"
```

Outputs to

```
<div style>...</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular sanitizes CSS variables set in property bindings. You can bypass this behavior with DomSanitizer.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="dec()">-</button>
    <button (click)="inc()">+</button>

    <div [style]="style"> My height is set by CSS Variable </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div {
      height: var(--height);
    }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  height = 50;

  get style() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`--height: ${this.height}px`);
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  inc() {
    this.height += 10;
  }


  dec() {
    this.height -= 10;
    if (this.height <= 0) {
      this.height = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6s4rve)

You might find this [article](https://medium.com/@realTomaszKula/theming-components-with-css-variables-a952273fa9a4) interesting. It goes into details on theming Angular components with CSS variables.

Comment: I would like to set the css variable using Renderer2, before using the same renderer to add a class triggering a transition. How would you use bypassSecurityTrustStyle with renderer.setStyle?

Comment: You can pass `RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase` as a 3rd argument to `setStyle`, no sanitizer needed

Comment: @dav1d This comment saved me, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For those using the **latest Angular versions**. You can implement it either of these:

Use Renderer's `setProperty` instead of `setStyle`

**Example #1: Setting 1 CSS variable**

```
this.renderer.setProperty(
  // it can be this.elementRef.nativeElement 
  // or this.document.documentElement or any similar
  <ELEMENT>, 

  // we will set the "style" property of the element
  'style',   

  // the CSS variable you want to declare
  // be sure to encapsulate it in a back tick (`)
  `--height: ${this.height}px`     
);
```

**Example #2: Setting multiple CSS variables all at once**

> NOTE: If you're dealing with multiple CSS variables, avoid implementing it separately as what was done in Example #1 above, as this will replace those initially declared CSS variables and will only end up with registering the last setProperty code

```
this.renderer.setProperty(
  // it can be this.elementRef.nativeElement 
  // or this.document.documentElement or any similar
  <ELEMENT>, 

  // we will set the "style" property of the element
  'style',

  // the CSS variables you want to declare 
  // be sure to encapsulate all of them in a back tick (`)
  `
      --height: ${this.height}px;
      --width: ${this.width}px;
  `
);
```