# Control CSS variable from Angular 5

Tags: css, angular

Is there any way to control a CSS variable defined at a component's root level using Angular methods? In JavaScript, we have `document.documentElement.style.setProperty()` when we set at root level.

In angular, can we use ':host' to declare css variable for global access within component? or do we need to use something like '::ng-deep :root'?

The following question also remains unanswered:
[Angular: Use Renderer 2 to Add CSS Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916671/angular-use-renderer-2-to-add-css-variable)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes you can set variables in root scope:

```
:root {
  --main-color: red
}
```

Yes you can use `:host` selector to target element in which the component is hosted.

```
:host {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can also use, `:host-context` to target any ancestor of the component. The :host-context() selector looks for a CSS class in any ancestor of the component host element, up to the document root.

```
:host-context(.theme-light) h2 {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

Note: `::ng-deep` or `/deep/` or `>>>` has been deprecated.

Read more about it here: [special css selectors in angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors)

Just an additional information.
It works both inside ':root' as well as ':host'
We can set values to them by:

`constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }`
then
`this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'red');`

Comment: is it possible to set values for CSS variables also in host or host-context and access them in *.ts file? bcz my intention is to know CSS variable access, specifically.

Comment: ok. will try it out and get back on this. thanks a lot for the update.

Comment: @ashfaq.p, you are a life saver!

Answer (score 7):

The most constructive and modular way to use css vars in components (with viewEncapsulation) is as such:

```
// global css
:root {
   --main-color: red
   --alt-color: blue
}

// inside component component css
::ng-deep :root {
   --specific-css-var: var(--main-color)
}
:host {
   background-color: var(--specific-css-var)
}
:host(.conditional-class) {
   --specific-css-var: var(--alt-color)
}
```

**NOTE**: despite `::ng-deep` being deprecated, it hasn't been replaced yet (and has no replacement), as can be read in several [discussion like this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160)

Answer (score -4):

Best thing for each component like a background color with out using ::ng-deep (which sets bg for all children)

import the following

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
```

declare elementref in constructor

```
 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
```

then call the function ngAfterViewInit()

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = ' white';
}
```

this sets bg to white but you can replace it with a hex color as well, so you can do that with every component

Comment: i didnt plan to touch the DOM. I wanted to animate CSS property of multiple DOM by controlling single CSS variable. any possibility in that direction?

Comment: on CSS you can call the object and id at same time like this:

h4#firstname {
background-color:red;
}

or class
h4.classname{
background-color:red
}