# change width in ::before property using angular and css

Tags: css, angular, css-variables

How can I change the width value in ::before property dynamically? Want to achieve this:

[image: ProgressBar]

**ts:**

```
fillWidth: number = '50%';
```

**html:**

```
<div class="track">
  <div class="step featured-w" [ngStyle]="{'--featured-w': fillWidth}"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.track .step::before {
    height: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: var(--featured-w); // this is not working, to increase green part 
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
}
```

I tried this: [Assign variable to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2/35280715#35280715)

Comment: you are missing the unit `px` or `%`

Comment: @TemaniAfif tried that, not working

Comment: shouldn't it be [ngStyle]="{'width': fillWidth}"

Comment: @Duki want to change `width` in `::before`

Comment: show us how you tried that

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41371037/8583669 I think that you can't simply update the css variable using `[ngStyle]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control css variable from angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903552/control-css-variable-from-angular-5)

Comment: @TemaniAfif lie this `fillWidth: number = '50%';`

Comment: @johannchopin no, not helping that ansr

Comment: @PathikVejani Have you tried to update this css variable without using `[ngStyle]`?

Comment: @johannchopin yes, but it is impacting on grey area not green.

Comment: checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2