# Angular 2+ CSS Custom Properties (variables) with Renderer

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-renderer2, angular-renderer

I'm trying to convert Vanilla JavaScript code to Angular 2+.

In Javascript, I have a statement like this:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${cssVariableName}`, value);
```

In Angular, the only way I've found to replicate the above statement is like this:

```
renderer.setProperty(document.documentElement, 'style', `--${cssVariableName}: ${value}`);
```

The issue: If I have multiple custom properties being dynamically set at different times (--cssVariable1, --cssVariable2...). The Angular Renderer will overwrite the style property instead of appending to the style property.

Can the renderer be used to achieve this functionality? If not, is there a preferred way of using CSS custom properties in Angular? Thanks!

Comment: DId you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916671/angular-use-renderer-2-to-add-css-variable

Comment: Thanks for the link! This helps a ton, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could use is [ngStyle]. You don't need to use the renderer.

In your controller you can have an object with the css properties you want to apply.

Like this.

```
props = {'color': 'red', 'font-size': '18px'};
```

And then in your html you can use that inside ngStyle to apply those properties to an element.

```
<div [ngStyle]="props">Great example</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

Try using `Renderer2` Object `setStyle` method

```
/**
 * Implement this callback to set a CSS style for an element in the DOM.
 * @param el The element.
 * @param style The name of the style.
 * @param value The new value.
 * @param flags Flags for style variations. No flags are set by default. enum: 1 or 2, 1: Marks a style as important.   2: Marks a style as using dash case naming (this-is-dash-case).
 */
abstract setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags?: RendererStyleFlags2): void;
```

You need this

```
 renderer.setStyle(document.documentElement, `--${cssVariableName}`, `${value}`, 2);
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver! :D

I totally missed the flag param there and wasted an hour scratching my head!

Comment: This Solution works fine for me! The flag param 2 here is important!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setStyle` method

```
renderer.setStyle(document.documentElement, `--${cssVariableName}`, `${value}`);
```

Comment: setStyle adds a property to the style tag of the element and does append. However, the operation is ignored for custom properties and the property is not added.

Example:
`'--background', 'green' // Invalid`
`'background', 'green' // Valid`

Comment: please see @vikey's answer below. There's a third (and optional) parameter that needs to be set to 2 for these cases. I just tested it and I can confirm it works